# Sharepoint 2013: Create a script for updating a list view when i adda new field

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I have several lists created with several different views each one, it is asked to me to  create a sript that allows this: everytime a new field is added on the list, this field must be automatically be added to all the views that already  exists. I  need a script because there are so many  lists,  and so many views that its tedieus to do it one view by one. Is there anyway to do this programatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create an event receiver for the lists(suppose custom list), then add filed to all views.

Sample code:

```
SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();
                SPList list = web.Lists["TestListLee"];
                var tmpViews = new List<SPView>();
                foreach (SPView view in list.Views)
                {
                    if (!view.ViewFields.Exists("myField"))
                    {
                        view.ViewFields.Add("myField");
                        tmpViews.Add(view);
                    }
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < tmpViews.Count; i++)
                {
                    tmpViews[i].Update();
                }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Lee, it really  helped me!